# different version number gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

My compiledsdkversion is 23. My Android support library has a 24.0.0-alpha1designation at the end of the string which declares it on my gradle app file. Gradle is compiling with errors stating that the support library should not use a different version than the compiledsdkversion.Any ideas on how to get rid of this error. I don't know how to update the compiledsdkversion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the latest stable version of the Support Library, which is currently `23.2.1` as per the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).